# Join two tables with different fields in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to join two tables with different fields in mysql. I have the following data in the tables:

| AQuenteSan | AFriaSan | Realizacao |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.58 | 0.61 | 2023-11-14 |
| 0.52 | 0.64 | 2023-11-15 |

| dioxcloro | Realizacao |
| --- | --- |
| 0.02 | 2023-11-14 |
| 0.10 | 2023-11-15 |

Now I'm trying to join the data like this:

```
WITH
exp1 AS (SELECT AQuenteSan, AFriaSan, Realizacao FROM raddb.Reg_Residual WHERE Realizacao BETWEEN '2023-11-14' AND '2023-11-15'),
exp2 AS (SELECT dioxcloro, Realizacao AS Realizacao1 FROM raddb.Reg_Dioxido WHERE Realizacao BETWEEN '2023-11-14' AND '2023-11-15')
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM exp1 JOIN exp2;
```

And this is the result I got when executing the query shown above:

| AQuenteSan | AFriaSan | Realizacao | dioxcloro | Realizacao1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.58 | 0.61 | 2023-11-14 | 0.10 | 2023-11-15 |
| 0.58 | 0.61 | 2023-11-14 | 0.02 | 2023-11-14 |
| 0.52 | 0.64 | 2023-11-15 | 0.10 | 2023-11-15 |
| 0.52 | 0.64 | 2023-11-15 | 0.02 | 2023-11-14 |

But the result I want is just this:

| AQuenteSan | AFriaSan | Realizacao | dioxcloro | Realizacao1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.58 | 0.61 | 2023-11-14 | 0.02 | 2023-11-14 |
| 0.52 | 0.64 | 2023-11-15 | 0.10 | 2023-11-15 |

How can I get this result?

Comment: Why don't you use the proper JOIN conditions for this? What's the rule for getting the second result, but not the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a column to join them on. In your case, you could perform a `LEFT JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT * from raddb.Reg_Residual r LEFT JOIN raddb.Reg_Dioxido d ON d.Realizacao = r.Realizacao WHERE r.Realizacao BETWEEN '2023-11-14' AND '2023-11-15'
```

This will give you the result you want. The `LEFT JOIN` makes sure, you only get one instance of an entry in the first table.

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT raddb.Reg_Residual.AQuenteSan, raddb.Reg_Residual.AFriaSan, 
  raddb.Reg_Residual.Realizacao,raddb.Reg_Dioxid.dioxcloro,
  raddb.Reg_Dioxid.Realizacao1
 FROM raddb.Reg_Residual
 INNER JOIN raddb.Reg_Dioxid ON 
  raddb.Reg_Residual.Realizacao1=raddb.Reg_Dioxid.Realizacao1
```